# When creating an AMI is it possible to also set up the default username displayed in "Connect" section of an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Before when I used the Official Ubuntu AMI, the default username displayed was "ubuntu" in the Connect section of any instance. But now, after creating a new AMI from the base Ubuntu AMI the default username displayed is "root". Is it possible to change the default username displayed to "ubuntu" again in the Connect section of the instances that use my new AMI?

Comment: The usernames are actually hardcoded in the AWS Console.  It's not documented how to influence the selection, though, generally, adding the string "ubuntu" somewhere to the AMI name is enough.